# Keep track of the lifetime of a child process in C#

Tags: c#

Part of our job is interfacing with an ERP system. Some of the processes within that system can be automated by calling a specific exe called IMPAUT.exe in the base directory of the ERP system. I pass the ERP sub program ID to IMPAUT and it fires off.

Now, what IMPAUT does is determines if the ERP installation is a client or standalone installation, and then IMPAUT fires off a child process. This child process is either IMPACT.exe or IMPCSC.exe. Once IMPAUT has fired off the child process, IMPAUT dies. The child process continues to live for a while. The child process only dies when it has completed the command and has logged out of the ERP system.

The problem is, that while the child process is still alive, I can't call IMPAUT again, because only one instance of the child program may be logged in to the ERP system. I also can't monitor when IMPAUT dies, because the child process will still be alive long after IMPAUT has died.

I need to determine when the child process has died for the specific IMPAUT process that invoked it. So from the parent, I need to get the child process it invokes, before the parent process has died and monitor that child process' lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use Process.GetProcessesByName() from System diagnostics namespace to find the process and check with the Exit code property if it is still running or not.
If the ERP systems works cleanly with an exit code, then you could also check that something has worked/failed.
In case the name is not unique, look at the Process.MainModule and Process.Module property and use Process.GetProcesses for all processes.

Comment: I can't use Process.GetProcessesByName() because I don't know what the child process name will be. Secondly, there could be child processes with the same name, unrelated to my IMPAUT parent.

Answer (score 0):

may be below code may help

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_DomainUnload);

void CurrentDomain_DomainUnload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Here you can write to some file about te status 

    }
```

or

```
 Process.GetCurrentProcess().Exited event
```

Comment: Thanks you for the code. How would this code be used to get the child of a specific parent. How would I implement this?